# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'opacity' in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this error on Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'opacity' in undefined

I think it has something to do with `.each` function but I'm not exactly sure.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function startDemo(cb){
        $(this).fadeOut(400);

        $("#step-1").fadeOut('400', function() {
            $("#step-2").fadeIn('400', function() {

                $(".pair p").each(function(i) {
                    var i = i + 1;
                    $(this).delay(i * 800).fadeIn(400);

                    $("#step-2").delay($(".pair p").length * 800).fadeOut(400);
                });
                cb();
            });
        });
}

function nextFunction() {
    alert("test");
}


$("#play").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    startDemo(function(){
        nextFunction();   
    });
});

});
```

Comment: does it tell you the line the error is on?

Comment: I think one of the functions needs to return something.

Comment: You are declaring i after using it as an argument for the function. Also you are declaring using itself.

Comment: @floor It's on line 3 in jQuery.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Removed it but still not working.

Comment: You shouldn't remove it. You should update how you declare it!!!

Comment: Unrelated, but, remove `var i = i + 1;` and change `$(this).delay(i * 800).fadeIn(400);` to `$(this).delay( (i+1) * 800 ).fadeIn(400);` Also, edit the question/code as and when you make changes.

Comment: Try this: $(".pair p").each(function(index, value) {
    var i = index + 1;
    var self = $(this);
    self.delay(i * 800).fadeIn(400);

    $("#step-2").delay(self.length * 800).fadeOut(400);
});

Comment: `$(this).fadeOut(400);` What is this line of code supposed to do ? This will give an error. Try removing that line of code and try again.

Comment: @AleksiTappura: Please use a non-minified version of jQuery if you have to debug it